# How to set up an HTTP video-streaming server for 'tablet independent viewing'?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming

I have a situation in our lab where we have a lot of video tutorials and a lot of different tablets are being used by the members of the group. Everyone wants to be able to 'stream' the videos from the server machine. Since ubiquitous apps don't exists for various different tablets I was thinking of being able to set up a 'web page' like youtube (intranet only) for streaming so folks can view it via the browser. I'm open to other solutions too. I'm not sure how it can be done. I'm okay if it involves a bit of coding too, or if I can set up with something off the shelf.

What's the best I can do in this regard? Some tablets, support flash some don't, so would need to be able to cater to both types of devices. Is there a solution 'simple' enough to solve this problem? How can I stream content over http and how can I set up a server to do so? Never done anything like it and hence the question. A free solution is preferable. A paid would do so too, if it's really worth it.

Tablets being used: Android Jelly Bean, Amazon Kindle Fire, iPad, Nook HD/HD+, Blackberry playbook (rare, but a few members have it).

PS: I'm not sure if this is the right place for the question. Moderators: please feel free to move it to an appropriate forum if the need be.

Answer (score 1):

So many Open source Youtube like PHP scripts available , you can download that and install on one of the server and you will have your own youtube like video site for your intranet where you can than upload all your video and share links with your user.

```
  PHPMOTION
```

Try it out its one of the best.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple if you don't need real time streaming. Any web service such as apache can be used   for *streaming* and most mobile device support mp4. So, all you have to do is provide a URL to the video, and then browser in the mobile device would start the video player.

Comment: real time streaming is what is preferable. Not all videos are in mp4 format by the way...

Answer (score 0):

I use [Unreal Media Server](http://umediaserver.net/) and windows IIS.  In IIS I create the web pages containing instructions, info, lists, etc and use Unreal for the media streaming.  I use this for both internal and external users.  Windows, Apple, Android, it's not device specific.  You can also do live video feeds.